# Django Filters - ModelChoiceFilter Distinct Values from Field

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of distinct choices from my `msg_direction` field populate in my form. On selection and a GET, the filter is applied and the page refreshes with the filtered data. The code works up to the point I make the selection, where I get the following validation error using `ModelChoiceFilter`:
* Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

Here's the field definition in my model:

```
msg_direction = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here's the filter definition in my filters.py file:

```
msg_direction = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Message.objects.
                                 values_list('msg_direction',
                                 flat=True).distinct().order_by())
```

I have also tried `ChoiceFilter` instead but would rather work with a dynamically generated list from that field rather than specify a fixed list of choices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a `ModelChoiceFilter` is for choosing a model instance (so it expects the `id` of the instance), not for choosing from a list of values in particular column in the database. You should use a `ChoiceFilter` and pass the list of values from your database as list of choices. Nothing stops you initialising your `ChoiceFilter` with a list computed at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the clarification, dirkgroten! Here's what I've come up with:

```
def get_choices(model, field):
    choices = []
    for k in model.objects.values_list(field).distinct():
        choices.append((k[0], k[0]))
    return choices

msg_direction = ChoiceFilter(choices=get_choices(Message, 'msg_direction'))
```

Any further recommendations for efficiency?